# How do you handle a stateless component that will trigger a store roundtrip when calling a callback until it comes back with the new props?

Tags: optimization, reactjs, store

Let's say I have the following component:

```
class TagsFilter extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    tags: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.string),
    onChange: React.PropTypes.func
  }

  onSelectTag = (tag)=>{
    this.props.onChange(this.props.tags.concat([tag]))
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className='tags-filter'>
        <SelectedTags tags={this.props.tags}/>
        <TagsSelector tags={this.props.tags} onSelect={this.onSelectTag}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Now, I know that when I call the parent with the new tags it's going to trigger a chain reaction, hit the store, update the list filter there, and cascade the new changes until it comes back again as new props to this component.

The issue is that when it hits the store it triggers server queries and other components updates that make the app stutter for a second, and the update of the TagsFilter component feels sluggish.

So I came up with doing the following:

```
class TagsFilter extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    tags: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.string),
    onChange: React.PropTypes.func
  }

  componentWillMount () { this.componentWillReceiveProps(this.props) }
  componentWillReceiveProps (np) {
    this.setState({tags: np})
  }

  onSelectTag = (tag)=>{
    let newTags = this.props.tags.concat([tag])
    this.setState({tags: newTags})
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.props.onChange({tags: newTags})
    }, 50)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className='tags-filter'>
        <SelectedTags tags={this.state.tags}/>
        <TagsSelector tags={this.state.tags} onSelect={this.onSelectTag}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Now, this definitively feels snappier. But I'm not sure if it's the appropriate way to handle these situations. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do a comparison in componentWillReceiveProps and only setState if different. You don't need componentWillMount. Here is an example, this is the standard pattern for input.

```js
import React from 'react';

class JInputRender extends React.Component {
   render() {
    let inputSty = this.props.input.style ? this.props.input.style : {color: 'red'};
    let textValue = this.state.textValue;
    let colorValue = this.props.input.colorValue ? this.props.input.colorValue : '#1A3212';
    let checkedValue = (this.props.input.checkedValue != null) ? this.props.input.checkedValue : false;
    let numberValue = this.props.input.numberValue ? this.props.input.numberValue : 0;
    let radioValue = this.props.input.radioValue ? this.props.input.radioValue : '';
    let radioChecked = (this.props.input.radioChecked != null) ? this.props.input.radioChecked : false;
    let min = this.props.input.min ? this.props.input.min : 0;
    let max = this.props.input.max ? this.props.input.max : 100;
    let step = this.props.input.step ? this.props.input.step : 1;
    let inputType = this.props.input.type ? this.props.input.type : 'text';

    let returnRadio = (
        <input
          ref="inputRef"
          type={inputType}
          style={inputSty}
          checked={radioChecked}
          value={radioValue}
          onChange={this.handleValueChange} />
      )

    let returnChecked = (
        <input
          ref="inputRef"
          type={inputType}
          style={inputSty}
          checked={checkedValue}
          onChange={this.handleCheckedChange} />
      )

    let returnColor = (
        <input
          type={inputType}
          ref="inputRef"
          style={inputSty}
          value={colorValue}
          onChange={this.handleValueChange} />
      )

    let returnNumber = (
        <input
          type={inputType}
          ref="inputRef"
          style={inputSty}
          value={numberValue}
          min={min} max={max} step={step}
          onChange={this.handleValueChange} />
      )

    let returnText = (
        <input
          type={inputType}
          ref="inputRef"
          style={inputSty}
          value={textValue}
          onChange={this.handleTextValueChange} />
      )
    let returnIt = {};
    switch (inputType) {
      case 'checkbox': returnIt = returnChecked; break;
      case 'radio': returnIt = returnRadio; break;
      case 'color': returnIt = returnColor; break;
      case 'number':
      case 'range': returnIt = returnNumber; break;
      default: returnIt = returnText; break;
    }

    return (returnIt);
  }
}

export default class JInput extends JInputRender {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {textValue: ''};
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    if (this.props.input.textValue) this.setState({textValue: this.props.input.textValue});
    if (this.props.input.focus) this.refs.inputRef.focus();
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
    if (nextProps.input.textValue && (this.state.textValue != nextProps.input.textValue))
      {this.setState({textValue: nextProps.input.textValue});}
  }

  handleCheckedChange = (event) => { this.props.handleChange(this.props.input.name, event.target.checked); }
  handleTextValueChange = (event) => {
    let newValue = event.target.value;
    this.setState({textValue: newValue});
    this.props.handleChange(this.props.input.name, newValue);
  }
  handleValueChange = (event) => { this.props.handleChange(this.props.input.name, event.target.value); }
}
```

Comment: But `componentWillReceiveProps` doesn't get called the first time when the component mounts.

Comment: Your right, I use componentDidMount for the initial setState.